# Can a regex point to a list to find matches

Tags: regex, alteryx

Im currently using a Regex procedure in Alteryx to recognize an employee number in a PDF document and split the document into individual pdfs based on ee number.

[RegEx in alteryx flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4qJH.png)

Essentially what it does is find the term "Employee" on each page, returns the proceeding six digit number, splits the page out and renames the file using that number. This has, so far, worked fine.

However I have had some errors/kickouts and honestly I want to be more sure about the process, so my question is this:

Is there a way to have the regex point to a list of employee numbers (say in excel) and split the pages based on matching numbers within the pdf file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

dave

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx can't do it, but with Alteryx, just have another data stream that reads the list of Excel numbers, then [join](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/join-tool) your data stream to that. Assume your data stream is the L input, and the valid EmpNo list is the R input. Then:

- The L output is invalid data stream records: save these for further analysis.
- The J output is valid data stream records: continue processing them.
- The R output is valid employees not represented in the data stream; retain for further review if interested.